# UnknownHostException on phone but not emulator?

Tags: java, android, ftp

I have an FTPClient for my Android app, and running it through the emulator works just fine, like expected. When I try to run it on my device though (Samsung Galaxy Tab) it throws java.net.UnknownHostException

Any ideas? Has anyone encountered this before?

Just to note, I have got `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my code, and also, to be clear, **the error is not on my emulator, it is on my device.**

Cheers

Comment: May be try with URL instead of IP. I had this issue once with galaxy S.

Comment: @thinksteep: I was using a url, then I tried an IP, both had the same result.

Comment: May be do fresh installation of app and try.

Comment: I'm testing it through USB Debug mode, I thought when you went "Run" it automatically did that... I'll give it a go manually anyway.

Comment: You are sure the device has internet access? What if you try to access the address in a browser?

Comment: I don't think run completly uninstalls the app. It just deploys fresh set of code and restarts the app AFAIK. I may be wrong too.

Comment: Straight up had the same issue, hasn't fixed it. Any other theories?

Comment: @RobLourens: I hate sounding stupid, but... that fixed it. Turns out what I thought was my "WiFi Signal" was actually cell signal. I don't know this unit very well, its only a dev. machine on loan to me.. anyways, thanks Rob and thinksteep